# Partition shown as FFFF and unmountDisk is unable to unmount

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, partition

My Mac's HDD is not opening. When I enter `diskutil umountDisk dev/disk0` shows:

> At least one volume could not be unmounted

```
sais-MacBook-Pro:~ sk$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               101.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             19.4 GB    disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4
```

Comment: @klanomath - you're clearly the resident guru on this; I'd flag a mod or use the chat to get these pushed into the correct order as to which should be master/similar/dupe etc

Comment: @Tetsujin I have partly rewritten my answer to "Recover data from partition showing as FFFF" and added a link to "How do I recover/fix my OS X partition?" in case hexdump isn't available.

Comment: @klanomath - nice work, yet again.

Answer (score -2):

Try to boot from Apple_boot Recovery HD